# Building a CONNECT and trying to deploy Glassfish domain build fails

Tags: ant, glassfish

I'm building a CONNECT for HL7 compliant portal and get an error when attempting to deploy the glassfish domain.  Portal requires glassfish 2.1.1 below is the error i get.

Could not load definitions from resource com/sun/tools/appserver/ant
lib.xml. It could not be found.

recreate.glassfish.domain:

-backup.glassfish.domain.configuration:

-backup.glassfish.domain.certificates:

-deploy.create.glassfish.password.file:
     [echo] deploy.glassfish.password.file.path: C:\Users\PROGRA~1\AppData\Local
\Temp\2\glassfish43310913

-deploy.glassfish.asadmin:

-delete.glassfish.domain:

-deploy.setup.init:

-deploy.set.env:

-deploy.create.glassfish.password.file:

-deploy.glassfish.asadmin:

-create.glassfish.domain:

BUILD FAILED
C:\NHINC\deploy.xml:399: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
 "%AS_HOME%\bin\asadmin.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the
file specified

Total time: 0 seconds
C:\NHINC>

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has a similar problem, this version of glassfish is not supported.  I used the next version up and it fixed the problem.